# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreach

I'm trying to use Entity Framework to execute a stored procedure to populate a list but am running into issues because one of the stored proc parameters is an int.

Here's my code:

```
string param1 = "param1";
int param2 = 1;

List<MyEntity> myEntities = new List<MyEntity>();

using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    foreach(MyEntity myEntity in ctx.FindMyEntity(param1, param2)    
    {
        myEntities.Add(myEntity);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I have a similar snippet of code that is almost identical, but the second param is a string.  It works perfect and returns the anticipated results.

What can I do to make this work with an int param?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `FindMyEntity` function?

Comment: What does `ctx.FindMyEntity(string,int)` return? It sounds like it returns an `int`, in which case: quelle surprise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but am running into issues because one of the stored proc parameters is an int

No, you are running into issues because `ctx.FindMyEntity(string,int)` ***returns*** an `int`. And as the compiler quite rightly says: you can't `foreach` over that. Check that `ctx.FindMyEntity` is returning, vs what you **think** it should be returning.

Comment: Ugh... you are absolutely correct.  Its return type was set to (none), but I thought I had set it to something differenct.  Once properly setting the return type, everything is working well.  Thank you very much for pointing out my mistake!  :)